# React Dout in creation of the project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to create the react projet.
During the creation I'm getting these errors.
Please help me!

Creating a new React app in H:\React Projects\react-js.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...\n"}},"0.2.3-next.9b4'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Siva Rami Reddy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-26T05_06_09_438Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react-js/ from H:\React Projects
Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command

```
 npm cache clean --force
```

then create new react project

```
npx create-react-app yourapp
```